# Segmentation fault in C code using OpenMP and O0 in three nested parallel loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a function with the following code

```
        double*** calchr(int snr, int snf ,int snz, double*** shr,double*** shr_temp, double*** sef, double*** sez,double*** ser,double*** shf, double*** a1r_h,double*** a2r_h,double dr,double df,double dz,double dt, int singularity,int pmlthick)
    {
        int i,j,k,l;
        double temp,per_temp,sum1,sum2;
        int fi_pi_2,fi_3pi_2;

        for(i=0; i<=(snr-1); i++)
        {
            for(k=0; k<=(snz-1); k++)
                {
                    k+=pmlthick;
                    shr_temp[i][snf][k]=shr[i][snf][k];
                    #ifdef parfor
                    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) private(i, j, k, temp, fi_3pi_2, fi_pi_2, per_temp, sum1, sum2) shared(shr_temp, shr, a2r_h, sef, sez, a1r_h)  num_threads(THREADS) ordered
                    #endif                    
                    for(j=0; j<=(snf-1); j++)
                        {
                        temp=shr[i][j][k];
                        shr_temp[i][j][k]=temp;
                        if( i!=0)
                            shr[i][j][k]=(a2r_h[i][j][k]/dz)*(sef[i][j][k+1]-sef[i][j][k])-( (a2r_h[i][j][k]/(double(i)*dr*df))*(sez[i][j+1][k]-sez[i][j][k]) )+ a1r_h[i][j][k]*temp;
                        else
                        {  
                            {   
                            fi_pi_2=j+snf/4;
                            fi_3pi_2=j+(3*snf/4);
                            if(fi_pi_2>=snf)
                            fi_pi_2=fi_pi_2-snf;
                            if(fi_3pi_2>=snf)
                            fi_3pi_2=fi_3pi_2-snf;
                            shr[0][j][k] = temp + (0.5*dt/MI_0)*( ((sez[1][fi_3pi_2][k]-sez[1][fi_pi_2][k])/dr) + ((-1.0*ser[0][fi_3pi_2][k+1] + ser[0][fi_pi_2][k+1] - ser[0][fi_pi_2][k] + ser[0][fi_3pi_2][k])/dz));                         
                            }
                        }
                        shr[i][snf][k]=shr[i][0][k];
                        k-=pmlthick;
                        }
                }
        }
        return(shr,sef,sez);    
    }
```

num_threads(THREADS) is taking as an argument from the Makefile with the appropiate flag -DTHREADS=4 (for example)

When I compile the code with -O2 flags, segmentation fault does not appear. When I compile with -O0 flag (no optimization) a segmentation fault appears. The serial version of the code runs without any problems both in -O2 and -O0 levels of optimization. All the operations are additions and multiplications and the matrices are dynamically allocated outside of these functions. 
What may cause this problem? I've read around that, in parallel nested loops I have to declare as private variables the indexes of all the loops. I made it but the segmentation fault insists. In the inner loop I placed a printf message and seems to runs well up to a certain index number. I am wondering what causes this problem. Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: I would like to add that I have a variable called temp inside the third loop in which I assign values of an array. I privatize it but the segmentation fault insists.

Comment: You need to provide more code than you have now.

Comment: You can see the full code now

Comment: Your parentheses don't match up so it won't compile. You also mix 4 and 8 space indenting and your brackets are not placed in a uniform way. If you want people to take the time to find your bugs then spend some time making your code readable.

Comment: Some of your problems are in`shr[i][snf][k]=shr[i][0][k]; k-=pmlthick;`. `k` should be shared (even if you declared it private) and you can't have each thread modify it. Also each thread will write to `shr[i][snf][k]`.

Comment: The code has some comments that were removed. Thank you for the notices. But, if a problem exists, will it be present in -o2 version of the code also?